# Passing elements of multi-dimensional array in Ansible using Extra-vars

Tags: ansible, packer

I have a harness to build VMs using Packer that in turn calls Ansible (in local mode) to do the heavy lifting.
I'd like to be able to parameters to Packer (got that), which is passes to Ansible as extra vars.

I can pass an external variables files and also a simple variable such as the example below.

```
ansible-playbook -v -c local something.yml --extra-vars "deploy_loc=custom"
```

Thats okay, but I really need to pass  more complex array of variables, such as the examples below.
I've tried a number of formatting such as the one below and usually get some kind of delimiter error.

```
ansible-playbook -v -c local something.yml --extra-vars 'deploy_loc=custom deploy_scen: [custom][ip=1.2.34]}'
```

Role variable file

```
# Which location
deploy_loc: 'external-dhcp'

# location defaults
deploy_scen:
  custom:
     ipv4: yes
     net_type: dhcp
     ip: '1.1.1.1'
     prefix: '24'
     gw: '1.1.1.1.254'
     host: 'custom'
     domain: 'domain.com'
     dns1: '1.1.1.2'
  standard-eng:
     ipv4: yes
     net_type: none
     ip: '12.12.12.5'
     prefix: '24'
  external-dhcp:
     ipv4: yes
     net_type: dhcp
```

Answer (score 2):

I think it's more robust and readable to generate a yaml file and use that with `vars_files`.

Alternatively you can generate a json file and read and parse it using a file `lookup` and the `from_json` filter. Something like this:

```
- name: Read objects
  set_fact: deploy_scen={{lookup('file', 'deploy_scen.json') | from_json}}
```

However, if you really want --extra-var you can use the dict() function:

```
-e 'var={{dict(key1=dict(subkey1="value"),key2=dict(subkey1="value2"))}}'
```

Comment: Setting facts is basically the same for me as doing an 'include_vars" from a file, which I've already done.  We have a build script in scons (not my domain) that calls my packer/ansible scripts and the build guys wants to just feed in the IP addresses as enviroment variable or argument.  So having to create a file, scp over to vmbuild enviroment, and then subsequent cleanup is certainly less clean then just sending an argument/env.  So thats the background on why we want to go this route.  About an hour in on the dict() example above and not yet working, but it might do the trick. thanks much!

Comment: I suggested the set_fact because it might be easier generating a JSON than a YAML. It might be easier to receive the dict as a JSON in any case, maybe as an environment variable. Easier to escape things in bash than in --extra-var.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a json structure in to ansible via the extra-vars parameter.  You have to be a little careful to make sure it's set up properly though. You want to have the parameter look something like this:

```
--extra-vars {"param1":"foo","param2":"bar","file_list":[ "file1", "file2", "file3" ]}
```

When I do things like this I typically write a small bash wrapper script that will ensure extra-vars is set up properly and then invokes ansible.